# Test rail API throwing 401 Unauthorized error even with correct authorization

Tags: java, api, automation, authorization, testrail

I'm trying to establish a connection to test rail and passing the correct authorization but it throws 401 Unauthorized error.

The same code was works on a different test rail but is not working with new instance.

I have enabled API integration in test rail settings and generated the API Authorization key.
Is there anything else that I need to take care of to solve this issue?

```
public static void SendHttpRequest(String jsonStr, String runId)

            String URL = prop.getProperty("TEST_RAIL_URL") + runId;  
            //TEST_RAIL_URL - https://testrail.xxxxxx.com/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/
            java.net.URL urlObj = new java.net.URL(URL);

            HttpsURLConnection con = null;
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod(prop.getProperty("API_METHOD"));
            //API_METHOD = POST
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", prop.getProperty("API_CONTENT_TYPE"));
            //API_CONTENT_TYPE = application/json
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", prop.getProperty("API_AUTHORIZATION"));
            //API_AUTHORIZATION = Basic <base 64 encoded api key>

            System.out.println("Test Rail connection ready");
            System.out.println(con);
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream outObj = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            outObj.writeBytes(jsonStr);
            outObj.flush();
            outObj.close();
            System.out.println("API request made to Test Rail");
```

Console output:

```
Test Rail connection ready
sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://testrail.xxxxxx.com/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/56
API request made to Test Rail
Dec 24, 2019 9:37:17 PM com.testrail.integration.TestRailInt SendHttpRequest
INFO: 401Unauthorized
Dec 24, 2019 9:37:17 PM com.testrail.integration.TestRailInt SendHttpRequest
INFO: {"error":"Authentication failed: invalid or missing user\/password or session cookie."}
401Unauthorized
{"error":"Authentication failed: invalid or missing user\/password or session cookie."}
Dec 24, 2019 9:37:17 PM com.testrail.integration.TestRailInt main
INFO: Enter finally. Closing
```

I'm guessing its something to do with test rail setup (admin access) or network level issue.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to ensure your instance of Testrail has API connections available?

{{your_testrail_url}}index.php?/admin/site_settings#

You will need both options enabled: Enable API, Enable session Authentication for API.

Comment: Yeah i had that enabled. Anyway I was able to resolve the issue. The issue was with base 64 encoding for auth key.

Comment: @VarunPrakash could you please let me know how you fixed that. I'm also facing the same problem

Comment: @VarunPrakash Hi, I have probably the same issue. Could you please share the base 64 decode you did?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an auth header in the Base 64 string worked for me

```
  string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{UserId}:{UserPasswrd}"));
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
```